# What is the software to enlarge the display of an image file?

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, image-editing

I received an image from a person, and the lettering in the image is small although these letterings are really important for me. So I want to know if software exists to enlarge the display of the image (so that its lettering can be well read).

Comment: What OS? Does it have to free? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: OS is Windows 7 64-bit , what do you mean by "have to free" ?

Comment: *be* free. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: even a trial version is enough , not necessarily free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows built-in photo apps have a zoom in/out feature.

- Windows Photos app (Windows 8/10)
- Windows Photo Viewer (Windows XP/7)
- Windows Photo Gallery (Windows Vista)

You can also use the Windows built-in Magnifier.

1. To open Magnifier press the Windows logo key‌ <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (plus sign).
2. To exit Magnifier, press the Windows logo key <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> or select the magnifying glass icon , and then select the *Close* button on the Magnifier toolbar.
3. In full-screen view, your entire screen is magnified.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any image processing tool will allow you to zoom/crop & resize the image **but** if the text portion of the image is so small that it the information is unreadable then it can never be recovered.  Limited reconstruction might be possible and personally I would use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

1. Load the image and simply try zooming on the text *this might be enough for you*
2. If there is some structure to the text but it is not clear:

   1. **Crop** the image to the area of text only *this speeds things up*
   2. **Scale** the image **by a factor of exactly 2** - *other values actually make things worse due to interpolation*
   3. Run the **Sharpen** filter
   4. If sharpen made things worse **Undo**
   5. check with zoom
   6. if still not good enough but it looks like there is information there repeat the above.
      Start
      [image]
      Scale x2
      [image]
      Sharpen
      [image]

GIMP also has built-in forensic tools that can show hidden text. In the GIMP *Colors* menu are the *Threshold...* and *Levels...* tools and several other useful tools. There are also some specialised tools used for reconstructing the information in the fields of astronomy and forensics. If all else fails ask the person who sent you the information to send you a clearer, higher resolution, image or **better** the actual text.

Comment: the texts are spread accross 10 figures : each figure has text inside it. And this text inside each figure which is small.